# Showing/hiding content with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, hover, hide, show

I have content in a div that needs to be displayed only when I have a specific element in my page.

This is my css code:

```
.my-div { display: none }
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.show-div').hover(function() {
         $('my-div').show();
      });
   });
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<div class="my-div">
   <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
<a href="#" class="show-div">Show content</a>
```

It actually works fine except I'm not sure how to hide my content again upon moving the mouse away from my "Show content" link. Is there some sort of "unhover" method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$().hover()` supports [`handlerIn` and `handlerOut`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover1) parameters:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.show-div').hover(function() {
      $(this).show();
   }, function() {
      $(this).hide();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just to answer `Is there some sort of "unhover" method?` this part specifically you can use `blur` like so

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.show-div').blur(function() {
         $('my-div').hide();
      });
   });
```

Comment: [`.blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) is for when a field loses focus, and has nothing to do with hover events.  The closest equivalent to "unhover" would actually be [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/), which is what the second argument to `.hover()` maps to internally.